# LEGO Color Sensor - EV3

Tags: ev3, sensor-colour

My son is using his EV3 with a color sensor. He is using the sensor to test the reflectivity of different materials. Can you please tell me what the letters "PCT" stand for?

Answer (score 4):

Based on this [API reference](http://www.ev3dev.org/docs/sensors/lego-ev3-infrared-sensor/) and [this discussion of the color sensor](http://forums.usfirst.org/showthread.php?21194-EV3-color-sensor) it looks like "pct" is short for **percent** as in a ratio with 100.

David added in a comment:

> EV3 hardware developer kit provides a bit more info on what 100% means:
>
> > The output from the sensor within light sensor mode is a value between 0 – 100 where 0 equals no reflected light measured and 100 equals full light reflection.

Comment: The EV3 hardware developer kit provides a bit more info on what 100% means: "The output from the sensor within light sensor mode is a value between 0 – 100 where 0 equals no reflected light measured and 100 equals full light reflection."